# Unreasonable(?) and inconsistent rounding while converting numpy array to torch tensor

Tags: numpy, pytorch, rounding

Converting a numpy.array of floating points into a torch.tensor causes unreasonable (np_array1 is rounded at fifth significant digit) and inconsistent (np_array2 is rounded up while np_array3 is rounded down) rounding. Is there a way of avoiding this?

Input:

```
np_array1 = np.array([0.99995])
print(np_array1)
print(torch.tensor(np_array1))

np_array2 = np.array([5.99995])
print(np_array2)
print(torch.tensor(np_array2))

np_array3 = np.array([555555.99995])
print(np_array3)
print(torch.tensor(np_array3))
```

Output:

```
[0.99995]
tensor([1.0000], dtype=torch.float64)
[5.99995]
tensor([6.0000], dtype=torch.float64)
[555555.99995]
tensor([555555.9999], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Comment: I suspect that there's no actual loss of information as a result of the conversion here, but that PyTorch is simply choosing to *display* the information differently from NumPy - that is, the apparent loss of precision is purely a display artifact. What happens if you convert the tensor back to a NumPy array? Do you get the original values back?

Comment: That's it! Do you mind submitting your comment as an answer so that I can mark the question as solved?

Comment: I don't really have much experience with PyTorch, I'm afraid (I can't even persuade it to _build_ correctly on my current laptop, so the above comment was pure guesswork); I'd rather leave an answer to someone who knows PyTorch better. That person may be able to make recommendations on how to alter PyTorch's printing settings, for example. (You could always write an answer yourself, of course - self-answered questions on Stack Overflow are a thing, and are encouraged.)

Comment: I see, I was not sure what the etiquette is here since I have never posted before. Thank you for the advice!